# Why is the my function not being called in my SetInterval?

Tags: javascript

It's my first time using JS classes. I have a setInterval in a function but the function that is supposed to be repeating but I'm not sure why it's not.

```
    class Stopwatch 
    {
    constructor(isRunning, timer, timerTime)
    {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
        this.timer = timer;
        this.timerTime = timerTime; 
    }
    init()
    {
    // Put the element on the page with an id of start in a variable
    // Do the same for the stop button and the reset button
    const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
    const stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
    const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");


    // Add an onclick handler to each of the buttons
    // Use the functions startTimer, stopTimer and resetTimer 
    startButton.onclick = this.startTimer;
    stopButton.onclick = this.stopTimer;
    resetButton.onclick = this.resetTimer;
    }
    startTimer() 
    {
        // if the timer is NOT running, start it
        // call the function incrementTimer every second
        // save the timer in a the timer variable

        if(!this.isRunning)
        {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.timer = setInterval(this.incrementTimer, 1000);

        }
    }

    incrementTimer() 
    {
        // increment the timerTime
        // calculate the number of minutes and seconds
        this.timerTime++;
        let minutes = Math.floor(this.timerTime / 60);
        let seconds = this.timerTime % 60;
        // write the minutes and seconds to the elements on the page
        // use the function pad to make sure there's a leading 0 if necessary
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = this.pad(this.minutes);
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = this.pad(this.seconds);

    }

    pad(number) 
    {
        // add a leading 0 if the number is < 10
        if(number < 10)
            number = "0" + number;

        return number;
    }

    stopTimer() 
    {
        // if the timer is running, stop it
        if(this.isRunning)
        {
            isRunning = false;
            timer = clearInterval(timer);
        }

    }

    resetTimer() 
    {
        // stop the timer
        this.stopTimer();

        // set the timerTime back to 0
        this.timerTime = 0;

        // write 00 to the elements on the page for minutes and seconds
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "00";
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    }
}



let stopwatch = new Stopwatch(false, null, 0);

// When the page has finished loading, call the function init
window.onload = stopwatch.init();
```

Comment: isRunning is false

Comment: `this.isRunning` vs `isRunning` are not same thing, same with `timer`, in stopTimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `onclick` property of an element, the function you assign will always be called with the `this` value set to the element. Thus, the properties of `this` that you try to access will not be defined.

Instead of:

```
startButton.onclick = this.startTimer;
```

Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` value the function will be called with:

```
startButton.onclick = this.startTimer.bind(this);
```

Also, your code for incrementing the timer is incorrect:

```
let minutes = Math.floor(this.timerTime / 60);
let seconds = this.timerTime % 60;
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = this.pad(this.minutes);
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = this.pad(this.seconds);
```

`this.minutes` is undefined as you used `let` to declare minutes and seconds. Instead, just reference the variables using their names--i.e., `minutes` and `seconds`.

```
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = this.pad(minutes);
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = this.pad(seconds);
```

When you are stopping the timer, you forgot to add `this` in front of the property you were trying to access.

This:

```
if(this.isRunning){
    isRunning = false;//isRunning is not defined as a local or global variables
    timer = clearInterval(timer);//timer is not defined
}
```

Should be:

```
if(this.isRunning){
  this.isRunning = false;
  this.timer = clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Demo:

```html
<button id="start">
Start
</button>
<button id="stop">
Stop
</button>
<button id="reset">
Reset
</button>
<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>
<script>
    class Stopwatch 
    {
    constructor(isRunning, timer, timerTime)
    {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
        this.timer = timer;
        this.timerTime = timerTime; 
    }
    init()
    {
    // Put the element on the page with an id of start in a variable
    // Do the same for the stop button and the reset button
    const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
    const stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
    const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");


    // Add an onclick handler to each of the buttons
    // Use the functions startTimer, stopTimer and resetTimer 
    startButton.onclick = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    stopButton.onclick = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
    resetButton.onclick = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
    }
    startTimer() 
    {
        // if the timer is NOT running, start it
        // call the function incrementTimer every second
        // save the timer in a the timer variable
        if(!this.isRunning)
        {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.timer = setInterval(this.incrementTimer.bind(this), 1000);
        }
    }

    incrementTimer() 
    {
        // increment the timerTime
        // calculate the number of minutes and seconds
        this.timerTime++;
        let minutes = Math.floor(this.timerTime / 60);
        let seconds = this.timerTime % 60;
        // write the minutes and seconds to the elements on the page
        // use the function pad to make sure there's a leading 0 if necessary
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = this.pad(minutes);
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = this.pad(seconds);

    }

    pad(number) 
    {
        // add a leading 0 if the number is < 10
        if(number < 10)
            number = "0" + number;

        return number;
    }

    stopTimer() 
    {
        // if the timer is running, stop it
        if(this.isRunning)
        {
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.timer = clearInterval(this.timer);
        }

    }

    resetTimer() 
    {
        // stop the timer
        this.stopTimer();

        // set the timerTime back to 0
        this.timerTime = 0;

        // write 00 to the elements on the page for minutes and seconds
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "00";
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    }
}



let stopwatch = new Stopwatch(false, null, 0);

// When the page has finished loading, call the function init
window.onload = stopwatch.init();
</script>
```